# How to generate Rails Migration class automatically from MYSQL database instance?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-migrations

I have database scripts which create database with more than 100 tables and lot of data. It is a tedious task for me to create Rails Migration classes for whole database. But i see Rails Migration as a good option in long term database change management. Please suggest some way to generate Rails Migrate classes automatically from MYSQL database instance.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done in three simple steps:

1. write config/database.yml to reference your database.
2. Run "rake db:schema:dump" to generate db/schema.rb.  Here's the
   documentation:

   $ rake -T db:schema:dump
   ...
   rake db:schema:dump # Create a db/schema.rb file that can be
   portably used against any DB supported by AR
3. Convert schema.rb into db/migrate/XXXXXX_create_migration.rb:

```
class CreateMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    # insert schema.rb here
  end

  def self.down
    # drop all the tables if you really need
    # to support migration back to version 0
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to generate data scripts also. What command should i use for same?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/). Its a Ruby library that does all the same things but without tethering you to Rails/ActiveRecord. It might be just what you need if you are thinking really long term.