# Rails - autogenerate migrations from database changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Is it possible to use Rails to auto-generate a migration based on changes that took place in the database outside of Rails since the last migration?

I know that running db:migrate will change the schema.rb to match what's in the database.... (at least if don't make any migrations but I do change the database in some way manually).  What I'm wondering is, if there is a way as part of that same mechanism or process to have it create a migration out of those changes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something Rails would do or is trying to solve.  Rails wants you to explicitly manage those changes through migrations so that your database is under control (and source control).

See if this gem is what you want. - https://github.com/pjhyett/auto_migrations

It might not work with Rails 3.  I think since you edit your DB directly you'd have to run `rake db:schema:dump` to update the schema.rb file.

If you want to capture the deltas between the different db change points then see this SO answer:
[How to generate Rails Migration class automatically from MYSQL database instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808437/how-to-generate-rails-migration-class-automatically-from-mysql-database-instance) , just repeat his steps along the way.